# Reactjs Redux Optimization Best Practices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, frontend

My question may seem dumb to the experienced but hey, I am just trying to learn. In a react-redux-thunk setup or for that matter any similar setup, should I use complex joins at backend or return normalized values to the front end as much as possible and use something like redux selectors to perform something similar to joins.

The second approach it feels will let me keep the state light but at the same time without proper algorithms, things can get messy. Like running three nested loops increasing time complexity etc.

Any thoughts or pointers to articles on best practices in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Should I use complex joins at backend?

Yes. In case if you have `complex logic/data structure` and need more **computational power to do calculation/mutation with the data**.

Try avoiding too many computation at UI for better user experience.

> Server side languages `Java, C# etc...` shine well for this use case.

(or)

#### Return normalized values to the front end as much as possible and use something like redux selectors to perform something similar to joins?

Yes. In case if you have plain data structures and you are not performing too many manipulations of any nested structure at UI.

Check [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) for the ways to normalise your redux **store** data.

As a normal user, I am `ok to wait a fraction of second more for server response` whereas any lag in using my application after loading is not better experience (Clicking/Navigate to other tabs etc...).

To answer your question in one word: **It depends**.

Remember only **user experience** matters at the end.